# If I change nvarchar(30) to nvarchar(256), when is the disk space allocated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, storage

We have got a big table with hundreds of thousands of rows, and say, 20, columns. One of the columns is of type `nvarchar(30)`. If I change this to `nvarchar(256)`, because a few of the rows need to store more data there, but not all, then:

- does this immediately change the disk allocation of the database?
- is the disk allocation dependent on whether or not the values in the cells exceeds 30?
- are the cells allocated separately, ie will one simple row exceeding size 30 affect the disk allocation size of the others?

I tried to google this but only found comparisons of `nvarchar(n)` with `nvarchar(MAX)`. Please note that my scenario does not include out-of-row storage, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be a metadata only change - rows only consume as much storage for variable length data as they actually require. So an `nvarchar(256)` column where no row actually contains more than 30 characters will consume exactly as much disk space as an `nvarchar(30)` column.

Comment: And if a few of them contain more than 30 chars, the disk consumption of the others will still not be affected?

Comment: The amount of storage used is determined on a row-by-row basis - but rows have to fit onto pages (8K each), so if all of the rows previously fitted *exactly* into their pages then these new oversize rows could cause more pages to be allocated.

Comment: Before the change you have `VARCHAR(30)` so in each row you can not have more that 30 symbols. After the change data will remain the same, but you can add and update up to 256 characters in that column.